# jQuery Animate - Move DIV to X, Y position with a fixed speed

Tags: javascript, jquery

My current jQuery code moves an element to an X and Y position on my page, however I would like a constant speed, regardless of distance.

For an example, if I move a short distance, the time will be slow. If I move to a further distance, the div will shoot to the position quickly, this is not what I want but I am unsure of how to change this.

```
$("#myAvatar").offset({ top: y, left: x})
```

I'm using the above code, would love to see how it is possible to have a fixed speed regardless of the distance the element moves.

Sorry if I am being vague or this question is hard to understand, will gladly clarify.

Edit**

The CSS is

```
transition: left 1.2s cubic-bezier(.42,-0.3,.78,1.25), top 1.2s cubic-bezier(.42,-0.3,.78,1.25);
```

The transition speed, 1.2s is what I should be fixing here. I am unsure of how to dynamically adjust this in JavaScript/jQuery to achieve the same speed whatever the distance between the X and Y point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a constant speed then use 'linear' rather than 'cubic-bezier(..)'

Answer (score 0):

you can use .animate()

```
$("#myAvatar").animate({ top: y, left: x},1200);
```

1200 is just a duration you can change it with duration you like but 1200 = 1.2s you have in css